# customizing css in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

okay so I have just started development using twitter bootstrap. I find it very handy and easy to use. But when it comes to applying my own styles and adding my own background color, links color, button color and font colors It gets really frustrating. I therefore need some good and complete resources or any tutorial that explains how to add our own css in the existing bootstrap framework. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You can study everything from there own website

Comment: @DineshKanivu their*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to customize the appearance of twitter bootstrap framework then:

1. always use a **custom.css** file to **override the main bootstrap.css**.
2. include it under your bootstrap.css
3. always see [getting-started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) at bootstrap site.
4. see this site [bootstrap-resources](http://bootstraphero.com/the-big-badass-list-of-twitter-bootstrap-resources)

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Fonts and colours can be customised on the bootstrap webpage. Adding backgrounds and things can be achieved by creating your own custom.css which can be included after the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your resources on getbootstrap.com. I would recommend you read their component documentation so you can understand what is offered and align it with what you need, that way you can avoid a bloated stylesheet.

Also chrome has a great tool that allows you to edit CSS on the fly (which I find more useful and quicker than using Firefox's extensions)

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but - when you read a bit more carefully you're getting all the information you want on the project's page(s):

On [the project page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) is a little tool where you can customize all LESS variables, at [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) is a README on how to compile the LESS files from scratch. Have a look at [the LESS homepage](http://lesscss.org) to get a clue about what LESS actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to build a CSS selectors with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), than those defined in bootstrap's CSS. See nice explanation here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In78mSOHmls

And you can use the built-in [Firefox Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) tool to see, which rules are applied and which are overriden. (it can be started by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> shortcut, in Chrome it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> )